# App Store 150x150 icons sizes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

On my iPad in App Store I can see 150x150 px icons. And in iTunes 100x100. Are they, scaled down versions of my iTunesArtwork image? Or scaled up version of my 144x144 px version of icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're scaled down versions of the 1024x1024 images you upload when you submit your app to iTunes Connect